# Ruby array of arrays find by inner array value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have array of arrays, which looks like this:

```
a = [['1','1500','SomeName','SomeSurname'],
['2','1500','SomeName2','SomeSurname2'],
['3','1500','SomeName3','SomeSurname3'],
['4','1501','SomeName','SomeSurname'],
...]
```

I can get sub-array of this array with all rows containing '1500' value by `.each` function and simple  `if`, but if `a.length` is large, it's taking too much time! **How can I get all rows from  `a` with certain `a[1]` value, without iterating over  `a`?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Enumerable#`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) is what you are looking for:

```
a.find_all { |el| el[1] == '1500' } # a.select will do the same
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a few options, you could use a find:

```
a.find { |l| l[1] == '5' }
```

This would find the array that matches the first 5

You need to use find_all to find all:

```
a.find_all { |l| l[1] == '5' }
```

Comment: But will it find all matches, or only the first one?

Comment: Andrey has nailed it, I missed that you wanted all

Answer (score 1):

Use `select` to get all matching elements:

```
a.select { |e| e[1] == '1500' }
```